# Fastest way to update a fresh Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I would like to bring my Windows 7 installation up-to-date in a few hours without human intervention.

Currently (even with automatic updates enabled), these problems arise:

- Some updates require restarting (before newer updates can be installed)
- Winwdows Update only checks for new updates every 24 hours (at a certain (configurable) hour)

In practice this means I have to:

- manually click `check for updates` (or wait up to 24 hours)
- sometimes (for **optional** updates) click `install updates`
- sometimes restart manually (or wait at least 10 minutes)

Possible solutions:

- manually downloading from https://catalog.update.microsoft.com? (but the 700+ packages and only 25 packages shown per screen make this too cumbersome)
- WSUS? (but this is a home-PC (or Virtual Machine) not in a domain + where would I run the WSUS-server?)
- ...?

Comment: Note: This issue might happen to you after you reboot for the first time after all of the updates are done: [system32 missing, Completely bare desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/615249/system32-missing-completely-bare-desktop)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The WSUS Offline Update program is what you need:

http://download.wsusoffline.net/

It will download all updates for your selected operating system from Microsoft servers and compile them into an ISO, which you can then burn to disk and run on your machine to install them all. The best part is it has an auto reboot and login option which means you can leave it unattended to install everything in one go.

Answer (score 2):

If it's just one PC, for one time, I would go with the manual update. You can do that while you're using the PC. Just a few clicks and restarts, and you're done.

If you don't have a domain and multiple PCs, it's still possible to create images with all updates installed for rolling out on multiple PCs with DISM, ImageX, WinPE and so.

If you're just looking for a way to install updates on multiple PCs offline, you can give [WSUSOffline](http://www.wsusoffline.net/) a try. But with that you still have to download the updates once, and that's not fully automatic. Installing the updates on the target machine doesn'T require lots of interaction, though.

For completeness sake: 
If you have multiple computers and a domain/company environment, I'd use WDS and Imaging for setting up the PCs with already installed updates, and use WSUS for ongoing updates.

Answer (score 0):

This question may fit better on Superuser.
In a corporate environment the thing you are looking for is *Microsoft Deployment Toolkit*. It consists of several tools for creating images and deploy them over the network including *Windows Deployment Server*. An installation without human intervention is called *Zero Touch Deployment* in Microsoft-speak. You can read about it [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/alanlemarquand/archive/2010/01/22/deploying-windows-7.aspx)

But you need additional infrastructure for this so it won't fit your home network requirements. The fastest way there would be Slipstreaming. That means you integrate the updates into the install media. Some third party software is needed for that because this is not supported by Microsoft.

Checking for updates: ther is a CLI command for that `wuauclt`

```
wuauclt /detectnow
```

Initiates a detection event to the assigned update services (Windows Update or WSUS).